# How do you compare user selected multiple choice answer and return right or wrong response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am creating a multiple choice 10 question quiz. I have the data stored in a STORE. I've generated the first question to come up but I can figure out how to compare the user selected answer with the STORE to return a right or wrong response. This is what I've done but so far when I select an answer and his submit it just returns me to the start page. Any recommendations would be appreciated!

```
function userSelectAnswer () {
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let selected = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
    let correctAnswer = `${STORE[quizProgress].correctAnswer}`;
    console.log(selected);
    console.log(correctAnswer);
    if (selected === correctAnswer) {
        feedBackCorrect();
        console.log('correct');
    } else {
        feedBackIncorrect();
        console.log('wrong');
    }
});
}

function feedBackCorrect () {
    $('.quizHolder').replaceWith(feedBackCorrectTemp());
}

function feedBackIncorrect () {
    $('.quizHolder').replaceWith(feedBackIncorrectTemp());
}

function feedBackCorrectTemp () {
   return `<div class="correctTemplate">
            <h2>Correct!</h2>
            <button type=button class="nextButton">Next</button>
        </div>`
}

function feedBackIncorrectTemp () {
  return `<div class="incorrectTemplate">
            <h2>Wrong!</h2>
            <button type=button class="nextButton">Next</button>
        </div>`
}


<body>
<header role="banner">
    <div class= 'col-12'>
        <h1><a href="index.html">Human Anatomy Quiz</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="col-6">Score: <span class="quizScore">0</span></p>
        <p class="col-6">Questions: <span 
        class="quizProgress">0</span>/10</p>
    </div>
</header>
<main role="main">
    <div class="quizHolder">
        <img src="anatomy.jpg" class="anatomyPhoto">
        <p>How well do you know the human body?</p>
        <button class="startButton" type="button">Start!</button>
    </div>
</main>
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="datastore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please show the code you use to call the userSelectAnswer function. It sounds like you you never make it into this function and just submit a form. So the problem may be how you are calling it.

Comment: I just edited the code, I realized I had some spelling errors. This is what it looks like now. I call userSelectAnswer inside the start button for the quiz. In the console on the webpage I can tell the if/else is working depending on what answer they select. But when I put the function .feedBackCorrect (); and .feedBackIncorrect(); in it, it will now pull them up.

Comment: So is your problem resolved?

Comment: No when the function is called inside the if/else. It still wont bring up the template for the correct or wrong answer. Sorry I realize in my last reply I put "will now pull them up" i meant will not.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your html. Your problem may be there.

Comment: The html is pretty short but there it is. The question template that loads just replaces `.quizHolder`. That what I'm trying to accomplish with this feedback depending on if they get it right or wrong.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your jquery to replace the content to quizHolder element. This makes me wonder if you have left something out? css class that is hiding correctTemplate? Code that has already run and dynamically replaced quizHolder so that element no longer exists? Do you get any error messages in your browser console?

Comment: That exactly what I've done. When I've populated the question template I replaced quizHolder with it. So can I not do that again? What would be the solution? Adding a seperate id to that element?

Comment: Or can I not replace that element again with something else?

Comment: You need to keep the quizHolder element as you are referencing it repeatedly. So change your code from `$('.quizHolder').replaceWith` to `$('.quizHolder').html` so that you are replacing just the contents and not the whole element. You will need to do this when you populate the template.

Comment: YOU'RE A LIFE SAVER!!!! I replaced them with what you said and it is now working! You don't know how long I've been trying different things. haha thank you!